# Advantages and limitations of hyperledger composer over fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

What are the advantages of developing on hyperledger composer over hyperledger fabric ?
Also the limitations or things not supported by composer which is available in fabric ?

Comment: Have you seen this Blog post comparing development effort for writing direct Fabric code or using Composer?
https://blog.selman.org/2017/07/08/getting-started-with-blockchain-development/   It is a little dated, but an interesting read.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Hyperledger Composer is a complement to Hyperledger Fabric. Composer allows you to model your roles, assets and transactions and it can generate some of the lower-level code for you. With Hyperledger Fabric, you would be writing this code yourself.

This can be a good thing, or not so much, depending on your POV.

Hyperledger Composer cannot (yet, as of this date) exploit all of the features of Hyperledger Fabric, but that is changing rapidly and the intention is not to have it place any limits. That said, it is also likely that what you can currently do with Composer will satisfy most common usage.

Answer (score 1):

see this [article](https://blog.selman.org/2017/07/08/getting-started-with-blockchain-development/) for a side-by-side comparison.

[As mentioned below - edited], the current release of Hyperledger Composer cannot (yet, as time of writing) exploit all of the features of Hyperledger Fabric, but that is changing rapidly and the intention is not to have it place any limits. You can get a preview of this in the latest Hyperledger Composer 'next' v0.17.x release (a preview release) that uses Hyperledger Fabric v1.1-alpha.  This means functionality (such as for example cross-channel queries or encryption or great historian support)  would be available by calling out to the Fabric APIs and use the native function already available there. See this ticket for more info [HERE](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3120)

An example Below is of how it might be written in the transaction processor function inside Composer:

```
const response = await getNativeApi().invokeChaincode(myChainCode, [arg1, arg2, arg3], myChannel)

// do something here with response (as a developer)
```

Comment: I am brand new to hyperledger and blockchain. Can you please explain what `myChainCode` refers to? Is that a custom function that one can write?

Answer (score 0):

According my understanding Composer simplifies the blockchain implementation process. Basically it implements blockchains on top of a fabric blockchain runtime. It allows users to model blockchain in an abstract level using and generates relevant codes itself for some extent. Composer is more suitable for creating quick reusable POCs.